# Unable to start the web application from localhost:3000(ruby on rails)

Tags: 12.04, ruby, rails

I had created a demo web application by executing `rails tickets` and then i executed `rails script/server` to run it on localhost.

Initially i was able to execute the application in the browser by typing `localhost:3000` in the address bar, but then I deleted the folder tickets from my hard disk.

Now again i created the same folder but when i try to run it using the same command `rails script/server` it says that

```
vverma@l-vverma:~/railsExp/tickets$ rails script/server 
      create  
File exists - script/server
```

I tried deleting the script/server file but i still couldn't run the `localhost:3000` in the browser

Tried `rails s` as well, it gave the following output:-
http://paste.ubuntu.com/1317610/

But still i was unable to run the app on 'localhost:3000'

What is the solution to this

Comment: Looks like you're running rails 2.x - you might want to use rails 3.0 instead, it's got better support/documentation.

Comment: do i have to run this script/server command everytime i make any change in the code?

Comment: I don't know about rails 2.x, but in 3.x you don't need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command to start it is `ruby script/server` and not `rails script/server`
that is the solution :P